# Subset Over A List of Dataframes With Different Column Names and Multiple Selections

Tags: r

Given a list of data frames which have unique column names, the end goal is to extract rows where those columns match a criteria sequentially for each data frame. Example:

```
Sp1<-c("Elm","Maple","Oak")
Sp2<-c("Elm", "Aspen", "Oak")
Height1<-c(2,4,6)
Height2<-c(4,6,8)
Site_1<-data.frame(Sp1,Height1)
Site_2<-data.frame(Sp2,Height2)
Tree_List<-list(Site_1=Site_1,Site_2=Site_2)
```

Now to begin I know that if I execute the following code it will return the desired output for a single selection:

```
subset(Tree_List[[1]], Tree_List[[1]][1]=="Elm")
```

I also know that I can extract the desired output for multiple selections if I call for the column by its specific name:

```
subset(Tree_List[[1]], Sp1 %in% c("Elm","Oak"))
```

Since I am iterating over this with a for loop over all of the data frames in the list with same the column number but different column names my attempt was:

```
subset(Tree_List[[1]], Tree_List[[1]][1] %in% c("Elm","Oak"))
```

This unfortunately returns an output of

```
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

instead of the desired output. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do this using `lapply` to loop over the `list` of data.frame and subset

```
lapply(Tree_List, function(x) x[x[,1] %in% c("Elm", "Oak"),])
```

---

Regarding the problem in OP's code, the `Tree_List[[1]][1]` is still a `data.frame` with one column.  We need to extract the column as a `vector`

```
subset(Tree_List[[1]], Tree_List[[1]][,1] %in% c("Elm","Oak"))
#  Sp1 Height1
#1 Elm       2
#3 Oak       6
```